# How to shorten a Github.io webpage name

Tags: github, url-shortener

I just recently created a Github page to post my portfolio but the address is too long.
How can I get a shorter version?

Comment: https://docs.github.com/en/pages/configuring-a-custom-domain-for-your-github-pages-site

Comment: Based on the link on your StackOverflow profile (`ruedalibre.github.io/portfolio.github.io`), one option would be to make a GitHub pages website, and have your portfolio as a page. Perhaps something like `ruedalibre.github.io/portfolio/`.

Comment: Maybe this is what you looking for? https://pages.github.com/